# jQuery : How to remove class for all element on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I would like to know if some one can improve my code... Using jQuery I'm trying to apply a class on the element we just click and disable this class on the other elements.

You will se in my code that I'm trying to apply a class on the  I just clicked and remove all the class on the others elements.

But for the moment, I'm doing it the "easy and mega long way" as you can see in *$("choice1-1").click(function()*

Can some help me with a code that could detect all the others ID ?

**Here my code for the moment**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#stick-question-1').mouseenter(function() 
    {
        $('#stick-choices-1').show();

    });

    $('#stick-choices-1').mouseleave(function() 
    {
        $('#stick-question-1').show();
        $('#stick-choices-1').hide();
    });


    $("choice1-1").click(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass('hover-etat');
        $("#choice1-2").removeClass('hover-etat');
        $("#choice1-3").removeClass('hover-etat');
        $("#choice1-4").removeClass('hover-etat');
    });

});
```

And my HTML is like this

```
    <div id="stick-choices-1" class="stick-choices">
        <a href="#" onclick="displayChoice1('Under 3\'9'); return false;" id="choice1-1">Under 3'9</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="displayChoice1('4\' to 5\'2'); return false;" id="choice1-2">4' to 5'2</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="displayChoice1('5\'3 to 5\'7'); return false;" id="choice1-3">5'3 to 5'7</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="displayChoice1('5\'8 and more'); return false;" id="choice1-4">5'8 and more</a>        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
$("#stick-choices-1 a").click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.hover-etat').removeClass('hover-etat');
        $(this).addClass('hover-etat');
    });
```

I've changed your initial selector, so that the `click` event is triggered by clicking any of the links within the `#stick-choices-1` `div` element, it prevents the default action of clicking the link (assuming that you want the default to be stopped), removes the `hover-etat` class from any element that *has* that class, and then applies that class-name to the `this` element.

It may, though, make sense to restrict the scope in which jQuery searches for elements with the `hover-etat` class, to those elements within the same `#stick-choices-1` element, rather than the whole document:

```
$("#stick-choices-1 a").click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#stick-choices-1 .hover-etat').removeClass('hover-etat');
        $(this).addClass('hover-etat');
    });
```

Or:

```
$("#stick-choices-1 a").click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.hover-etat').removeClass('hover-etat');
        $(this).addClass('hover-etat');
    });
```

Comment: Though I would remind you to consider accepting an answer, if one of us has solved your problem. Not necessarily mine, but whichever answer most helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It will works fine :

```
$("#choice1-1").click(function(){
    $(".stick-choices a").each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass(".hover-etat");
    });
    $(this).addClass(".hover-etat");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, and registers this handler for *all* of the links.

```
$('#stick-choices-1 > a').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).addClass('hover-etat').siblings().removeClass('hover-etat');
    ...
});
```

Note the use of `.siblings()` to ensure that only the links that are in the same group are affected, and without sending an unnecessary class change to the clicked link.

Answer (score 0):

This click event will work for all of the choices:

```
$('.stick-choices a').click(function(e){
    $(this).siblings('.hover-etat').removeClass('hover-etat');
    $(this).addClass('hover-etat');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.stick-choices a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).addClass('hover-etat').siblings('a').removeClass('hover-etat');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> $("a", $("#stick-choices-1")).click(function(){
>
> ```
>    $(".hover-etat").removeClass('hover-etat');
>    $(this).addClass('hover-etat');
> ```
>
> });

May be something like this?